# Object instanceof Object

Tags: java

I want to check if an object is instance of an objects class.

```
public Stack<Object> getObject(int x, int y, int x2, int y2, Object type, Stats stats){
    Stack<Object> ob = new Stack<Object>();
    for(Object o : stats.map){

        if(o instanceof type.getClass()){//Not working 

            if((!((o.x < x && o.x < x2) || (o.x * o.size > x && o.x * o.size > x2)) && 
                !((o.y < y && o.y < y2) || (o.y * o.size > y && o.y * o.size > y2)))){
                ob.push(o);
            }
        }
    }
    return ob;
}
```

I have made some classes that exctends other classes:

(Tree, Iron, Stone) extends Resouce extends Object

Person extends Object

- If type.getClass() = Resource: Tree, Iron and Stone is supposed to return true.
- If type.getClass() = Tree: Tree is supposed to return true and Iron and Stone is supposed to return false.

Comment: Myself, I'd try to re-design my code so that this kludgy and code-smelling instanceof isn't needed. Perhaps you want to use a Visitor design pattern (not sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `instanceof` with `Class` objects.

You can check it using:

```
type.getClass().isInstance(o)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
if(o.getClass() instanceof type.getClass()){
```

Comment: Nope, we can't have `instanceof type.getClass()`. Please test your answer before posting it. This is not a race (as many assumes).